# Stop text from moving when resizing window

Tags: html, css

When I resize my window all the elements move around and I want them to stay in the right place. How do I do that? Do I need to put them in a wrapper or something?

HTML -

```html
<div id="menu">
    <div class="table">
        <ul id="horizontal-list">
            <li><a href="index.html" class="no-underline" >Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="page2.html" class="no-underline" >All About</a></li>
            <li><a href="page3.html" class="no-underline" >Galley</a></li>
            <li><a href="page4.html" class="no-underline" >Video Clips</a></li>
            <li><a href="page5.html" class="no-underline" >Main Cast</a></li>
        </ul>   
    </div>  
</div>
```

CSS -

```css
#menu-outer {
    height: 84px;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
}

.menu {
    display: table;
    position: fixed;
}

ul#horizontal-list {
    min-width: 700px;
    list-style: none;
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 50px;
}

ul#horizontal-list li {
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 50px;
}
```

Comment: So far as I know, the text has to move to adjust to the new container size. If it doesn't, it will overlap.

Comment: You (could) set your container to `overflow: hidden;` and give everything a fixed width. That will keep things from shifting around, but any given user may not be able to click/touch any given link since it will be hidden from view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed you have this in the CSS.

```
.menu {
    display: table;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Is it supposed to be `#menu`, in order to match the markup?

```
#menu {
    display: table;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/60admLna/